# Making text move with the rectangle it is on top of

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am new to silverlight and so I may just be missing something due to my lack of knowledge. I am writing an app that uses Rectangles that you can click and drag to around the screen after they are generated. I have function that generates the rectangles:

```
    public void formatBox(block b)
    {
        Rectangle Rec = new Rectangle();
        Rec.Height = 100;
        Rec.Width = 200;
        SolidColorBrush newBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        newBrush.Color = b.blockColor;
        SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
        Rec.StrokeThickness = 4;
        Rec.Stroke = blackBrush;
        Rec.Fill = newBrush;
        Canvas.SetTop(Rec, generateY(b.locationY));
        Canvas.SetLeft(Rec, generateX(b.locationX));
        TextBlock blockname = new TextBlock();
        blockname.Text = b.blockText;
        blockname.FontSize = 25;
        canvas1.Children.Add(Rec);
        canvas1.Children.Add(blockname);
        Binding topbinding = new Binding("Top");
        Binding leftbinding = new Binding("Left");
        topbinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        leftbinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        topbinding.Source = Rec.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
        leftbinding.Source = Rec.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
        blockname.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, topbinding);
        blockname.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, leftbinding);
        Rec.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Handle_MouseDown);
        Rec.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Handle_MouseMove);
        Rec.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Handle_MouseUp);
    }
```

These rectangles are built from a block class

```
public class block
    {
        public double locationX { get; set; }
        public double locationY { get; set; }
        public Color blockColor { get; set; }
        public string blockText { get; set; }
        public block(double x, double y, Color c, string s)
        {
            this.locationX = x;
            this.locationY = y;
            this.blockColor = c;
            this.blockText = s;
        }
    }
```

And my mouse event handlers:

```
    bool isMouseCaptured;
    double mouseVerticalPosition;
    double mouseHorizontalPosition;

    public void Handle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle;
        mouseVerticalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).Y;
        mouseHorizontalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).X;
        isMouseCaptured = true;
        item.CaptureMouse();
    }

    public void Handle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle;
        if (isMouseCaptured)
        {

            // Calculate the current position of the object.
            double deltaV = args.GetPosition(null).Y - mouseVerticalPosition;
            double deltaH = args.GetPosition(null).X - mouseHorizontalPosition;
            double newTop = deltaV + (double)item.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
            double newLeft = deltaH + (double)item.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);

            // Set new position of object.
            item.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
            item.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);

            // Update position global variables.
            mouseVerticalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).Y;
            mouseHorizontalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).X;
        }
    }


    public void Handle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle;
        isMouseCaptured = false;
        item.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        mouseVerticalPosition = -1;
        mouseHorizontalPosition = -1;
    }
```

The text I am trying to move is called blockname in formatBox(). I have tried Binding as you can see here but I think there is a gap in my knowledge of an easier way to do this. Either way I would like the text to move when the block moves under it when the mouse event handlers are triggered. How do I get the text to move with it?

Comment: Why tag WPF if this is silverlight?

Comment: Because binding works similarly but it has been removed now to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mousehandlers already you could just skip the binding and use code. (The binding wouldn't work as expected anyway: the text would have the same coordinates as the reactangle so it gets drawn over the top/left lines of the rectangle. This will look ugly and make the text hard to read, you need to offset the text so that it's inside the reactangle or outside). Basically what you would do is in `MouseDown` put a flag high to idicate the mouse was pressed, and record the point where the mouse is. Then in `MouseMove` you check the flag: if it is on, calculate the new position for your rectangle as it's currentposition + the distance moved from the point recorded in `MouseDown`. The position of the text would then be the new position + some offset.

btw I suggest to split methods like formatBox into multiple smaller methods and choose better names for your variables: it will make the code not only more readable, but also more maintainable.

**edit**
to figure out which rectangle to move, do a hit test on all your elements in the MouseDwon handler. Something like this:

```
Rectangle rectangleUnderMouse = null;
foreach( var rec in rectangles )
{
  if( VisualTreeHelper.HitTest( rec, pointWhereMouseIs ) )
  {
    rectangleUnderMouse = rec;
    break;
  }
}
```

**edit**
sorry I didn't see you asked which textblock to move.. That is easier: you could keep a `Dictionary<Rectangle,TextBlock>` inside your main class:

```
public void formatBox(block b)
{
  //...
  myDictionary[ Rec ] = textblock;
}

public void Handle_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs args ) 
{
  //...
  textBlockForThisRect = myDictionary[ item ];
  //move textBlockForThisRect
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `MouseDown` would be triggered on the rectangle not the text. Is there a way to trigger a `MouseDown` event for the text when the mouse clicks the rectangle? I understand what you are saying about breaking up the method. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: you don't need the mouse events on the text: you move the text from within the mouse events for the rectangle

Comment: and how would I identify which textblock to move? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, and I can post my event handlers for moving the rectangle.

Comment: Edited my question with mouse event handlers. I have the logic to move the rectangles but not the text box. I think the Hittesting will work for it I just need to read up on it.

Comment: You're the man @stijn. Thanks for being patient with a newbie.